How to stream large .zip files from Azure Blob Storage directly to the browser?
Requirement
Support bulk download of files stored on Azure blob storage for the users either via .NET Core endpoint or through SAS URL from Azure
Specifications

Content Type? - application/zip
How huge is the data we're talking about? - Worst case - 5 GB

Backend specification

Containerized .NET Core WebAPI

Question
How do I go about implementing this? If I download the entire stream of data from blob storage to my .NET Core API, I think I would have to hold such data in memory before I could start transferring the data using below snippet.
return File("stream", "application/octet-stream", fileName;

I also looked around a few available resources online - Bill Tiherst which talks about streaming the Blobs stored on Azure Blob storage via .NET Core APIs with the help of Range-processing and I've tried that as well. It works via Postman but I do not think it would be feasible for my use-case since I cannot make multiple get requests while updating the values in the "Range" header so that the file downloads incrementally
One of the potential solutions I'm considering is generating a SAS URL (With READ permission) and expiry time from Azure blob storage itself and bind that with the download button on the UI using which the file download automatically starts. I think the benefit with this would be the middle layer (.NET Core) API would be eradicated and our infrastructure (CPU, Memory) would not get hampered
Any guidance, help or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

To stream large .zip files from Azure Blob Storage directly to the browser in an ASP .NET Core WebAPI, you can utilize a combination of Azure Blob Storage and a Shared Access Signature (SAS) URL. Here's how you can implement it:

Use the Azure Storage SDK for .NET to generate an SAS URL for the blob with read permission and an appropriate expiry time.

Expose an endpoint in your ASP .NET Core WebAPI to generate and return the SAS URL to the client if needed.

Used this doc to Create a service SAS for a blob with .NET Azure Storage.


The code below streams large .zip files from Azure Blob Storage directly to the browser in a .NET Core WebAPI, you can utilize the SAS (Shared Access Signature) URL.
 if (blobClient.CanGenerateSasUri)
        {
            // Create a SAS token that's valid for one day
            BlobSasBuilder sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
            {
                BlobContainerName = blobClient.GetParentBlobContainerClient().Name,
                BlobName = blobClient.Name,
                Resource = "b"
            };

            if (storedPolicyName == null)
            {
                sasBuilder.ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(1);
                sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobContainerSasPermissions.Read);
            }
            else
            {
                sasBuilder.Identifier = storedPolicyName;
            }

            Uri sasURI = blobClient.GenerateSasUri(sasBuilder);

            return sasURI;
        }
        else
        {
            // Client object is not authorized via Shared Key
            return null;
        }



 string accountName = "<storage-account-name>";
        string accountKey = "<storage-account-key>";
        string containerName = "sample-container";
        string blobName = "sample-blob.zip";

        // Create BlobServiceClient with account key
        StorageSharedKeyCredential storageSharedKeyCredential =
            new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
            new Uri($"https://{accountName}.blob.core.windows.net"),
            storageSharedKeyCredential);

        // Get BlobClient for the blob
        BlobClient blobClient = blobServiceClient
            .GetBlobContainerClient(containerName)
            .GetBlobClient(blobName);

        // Create service SAS for the blob
        Uri blobSASURI = await CreateServiceSASBlob(blobClient);

        if (blobSASURI != null)
        {
            // Create a blob client object representing 'sample-blob.txt' with SAS authorization
            BlobClient blobClientSAS = new BlobClient(blobSASURI);

            // Now you can use blobClientSAS to perform operations on the blob with limited permissions
            Console.WriteLine($"SAS URI for the blob: {blobSASURI}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to generate SAS URI. BlobClient is not authorized via Shared Key.");
        }










By using SAS URLs, you can efficiently stream large files from Azure Blob Storage to the browser without consuming memory resources on your .NET Core WebAPI server

